# Mysql PHP generated table: doesn't work with Tablesorter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, tablesorter

I found this great Tablesorter plugin for jQuery but I can't make it work with my PHP generated table. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function table() {

        $("#container").load("table.php?randval="+Math.random());

    }


    $(document).ready(function() { 

        table();
        $("table").tablesorter(); 
   }); 

</script>
```

Where #container is the div where the table will be and table is the name of the table. I get the table loaded but sorting function is not working.

It works if I put the table directly in html in the page.. but I don't see the point in having a static table for sorting.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.load() performs a asynchronous request, i.e. the function does not wait for the data to arrive before returning. Therefore `$("table").tablesorter();` is executed most likely before the table is added to the document. Either make it a synchronous call or (even better) pass a handler for the complete event to load.

http://api.jquery.com/load/:

> .load( url, [ data ], [ complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )
>
> **url** A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
> **data** A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.
> **complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)** A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#container").load(
      "table.php?randval="+Math.random(),
      null,
      function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
        $("table").tablesorter();
      }
    );
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot VolkerK! :) That worked like a charm.
I hope other users using Tablesorter with AJAX find your answer as useful as I did.